# How to execute (route) specific Javascript functions in one file, based on url, without a framework and interfering

Tags: javascript, oop, routes

Well, that's a loaded question (for search purposes), and potentially stupid.

I am experimenting for learning and I'd like to know what would be a great way to accomplish this.

All the reading I've done on routing addresses just the `HTML` part, and not the `Javascript` functionality once it loads.

Let's say this is the script file.

```
let path = window.location.pathname;

if (path.includes("/foo")) initFoo();
if (path.includes("/bar")) initBar();

function initFoo(){
  console.log("foo");

  function doSomething(){
    console.log("something 1");
  }
}

function initBar(){
  console.log("bar");

  function doSomething(){
    console.log("something 2");
  }
}
```

How can `doSomething()` be **called from outside**? The function is not available once the `init()` executes. If it's not inside an `init()`, then the functions collide.

Is this a classic `OOP` moment, where I'd have to create a `Foo()` and `Bar()` class where `doSomething()` is a method?

How would the code solving this look like?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, it is not accessible, because it's in other scope.

More verbose answer, solution would be to use closure to get reference to this function. For example by returning `doSomething` inside of `initBar`

```
function initBar(){
  console.log("bar");

  function doSomething(){
    console.log("something 2");
  }

  return doSomething;
}
```

So you can call it then as

```
const func = initBar();
func();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If there are multiple functions like that, would I return an object with all the functions?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: What if there a second function `doSomethingElse()`? How would you return two functions?

Comment: inside `initFoo` for example? Then do the same, `return` reference to that function and save it to variable and then call it when you want

Comment: I am not explaining it well. What if you want to return both `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` from inside `initFoo()`?

Comment: Well, I think I get it, if you want to return both `doSomething` from `initFoo`, you need either put both `doSomething` inside `initFoo` (but rename second function) and then return for example `{first: doSomething, second: doSomethingElse}`. Or you can define `doSomething` in different functions like `initFoo` and `initBar`, but then if you want to return both from `initFoo`, then you need to call `initBar` inside `initFoo` and do the same as in first option. Furthermore, you can also return an array of there references like `return [doSomething, doSomethingElse]`.Hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this depends on how you plan to apply this approach to whatever scale you're targeting for your Proof of Concept.

Having classes `Foo()` and `Bar()` each with their own `doSomething()` is definitely a feasible approach, but may not be necessary.

#### Are you able to assume that by visiting `/foo` that `doSomething()` will always be called?

Go with Dominik's answer:

```
let path = window.location.pathname;

if (path.includes("/foo")) initFoo()();
if (path.includes("/bar")) initBar()();

function initFoo(){
  console.log("foo");

  function doSomething(){
    console.log("something 1");
  }

  return doSomething;
}

function initBar() {
  console.log("bar");

  function doSomething() {
    console.log("something 2");
  }

  return doSomething;
}
```

#### Or might your `init` functions have more than one closure that you need to target?

In this case, you may be able to target your closures with a query parameter in your route:

```
/foo?method=doSomething
```

---

```
let path = window.location.pathname;

let params = Array.from(
  (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).entries()
);

function getMethodFromParams(defaultMethod = 'doSomething') {
  let [ method ] = params.find(function([ value, key ]) {
    return key === 'method';
  });

  return method !== undefined && method.length > 0
    ? method
    : defaultMethod;
}

let method = getMethodFromParams();
let action;

if (path.includes("/foo")) action = initFoo()[method];
if (path.includes("/bar")) action = initBar()[method];

action();

function initFoo() {
  const method = getMethod();

  console.log("foo");

  function doSomething() {
    console.log("something 1");
  }

  function doSomethingElse() {
    console.log("something else 1");
  }

  return {
    doSomething,
    doSomethingElse
  };
}

function initBar() {
  const method = getMethod();

  console.log("bar");

  function doSomething() {
    console.log("something 2");
  }

  function doSomethingElse() {
    console.log("something else 2");
  }

  return {
    doSomething,
    doSomethingElse
  };
}
```